# show the point value on mouse hover

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have the following plot. How can I show the point value on mouse hover. Could anybody help me.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4], [1,4,9,16], 'ro')
plt.axis([0, 6, 0, 20])
plt.show()
```

Comment: did you check matplotlib documentation

Comment: When you run this example, a matplotlib window will appear that shows the coordinates of your mouse position in the statusbar. So you need to be more specific in your question. What do you mean by "show the point value"? What did you already try in order to achieve that? You may look at [matplotlib event handling](http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html) to find out what is possible. You may then edit your question and ask about problems that you have implementing the desired behaviour.